# Is this element really a set?

Tags: nix

If I have a set, I can get easily a element of this set.

```
 { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }
```

> { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }

```
 builtins.typeOf  {a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }
```

> "set"

```
 { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }.a
```

1

Now I have another set

```
 builtins.typeOf (let f= builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; in let ff= f.outputs.devShells.x86_64-linux; in  ff.cosmos-shell)
```

> "set"

Ok that a set but it doesn't really look like a set ( «» instead of{})

```
let f= builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; in let ff= f.outputs.devShells.x86_64-linux; in  ff.cosmos-shell
```

> «derivation /nix/store/drfgr6zlkbv70wmml5n8h9x2wj29kk39-nix-shell.drv»

and I can't take the field derivation

```
 builtins.attrNames (let f= builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; in let ff= f.outputs.devShells.x86_64-linux; in  ff.cosmos-shell
```

give others field. That are  the elements used to build cosmos-shell

My question is why this command

```
  let f= builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; in let ff= f.outputs.devShells.x86_64-linux; in  ff.cosmos-shell
```

doesn't return
a set with the element defining cosmos-shell

or

another type giving the derivation where cosmos-shell is defined and with method to get the element defining cosmos-shell

**Why am I asking this question**

Normally I can easily export a set as a json string

```
  builtins.toJSON { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }
```

> "{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}"

But in this case I can't.

```
  builtins.toJSON (let f= builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; in let ff= f.outputs.devShells.x86_64-linux; in  ff.cosmos-shell)
```

'>""/nix/store/wf3inmq4x93s3z32m90xz8d10gkz55zb-nix-shell""'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't look like a set". You have an *expression* that evaluates to a set; that expression just isn't a set "literal".

Comment: If I recall, a derivation is just a set with a particular group of attributes.

Comment: @chepner I mean there is « instead of {.

Comment: I think that's just a special case for sets that look like derivations.

Comment: See https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/our-first-derivation.html

Comment: Also, look at how the repl prints `{type="derivation";}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A derivation is little more than an attribute set with the name `type` having the value `"derivation"`. (Whether such a set can be *used* as a derivation is meant to be used is another matter.) The Nix repl recognizes all such sets and diplays them in a special way.

```
> { type = "derivation"; }
«derivation ???»
```